# IOS just freezes

Tags: ios, objective-c, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I have a really nasty bugg somewhere in my code, that makes the the application unresponsive. It doesn't crash, It just makes everything unresponsive and I need to restart the app to get it to work again.

There are quite a few people that have reported this issue, but I have never encounter it myself, which makes it really hard to debug. I also can't reproduce it. 
However, this morning i finally got it freeze. I didn't do anything special with the app this time. I hit the "pause program excecution" button to get a stack trace (see below) 
I'm not quite sure if that stack trace has anything to do with the problem, but I'll post it.

Have you had similar issue? How do you debug a thing like this? 
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Here's a few things I do that might be the cause:

Timer

```
self.turnLefttimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.turnLefttimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

A ton of UIAnimations:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
         //Animations in here
     } completion:nil];
```

Game center callback, and using dispatch_async to get main queue.

```
 - (void)getMatchData:(void(^)(NSData *matchData))block {

    __weak GameViewController *weakSelf = self; 
    [self.gkMatch loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *matchData, NSError *error) {
       //Handle data 

        if (block)
            block(matchData);
    }];
}

    //In another function
    [self getMatchData:^(NSData *matchData) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

             //Do stuff with data
        });
    }];
```

Frequent use of blocks, operation queue and GCD, but make sure I dont use a dispatch_sync inside a dispatch_async block to create a deadlock.

Also use UIPanGestureRecognizer and UITapGestureRecognizer on the same view to move it around.

[image]

Comment: That stack trace means you have some kind of event being emitted to a responder, such as when a UIButton calls its selector on its target.  What was the last UI element you touched to get it to "freeze", and what is its associated selector?

Comment: I use AHAlertView instead of the default UIAlertView. I think that was the thing that was being called

Comment: Isn't this a regular 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' ?
Do you have details about the exception in the console?

Comment: If its a regular unrecognized selector, should the app crash?

Comment: Alright, now setup some break points in and around your calls to that object and see if it's blocking the main thread.  Animations are never the cause, they typically perform on a private queue; and NSTimers don't usually block the runloop because they are integrated tightly into the runloop.  It looks like AH is calling back to you through some kind of delegate method that you don't implement.  Still, that wouldn't "freeze" an app, that would just be a fatal exception.

Comment: @Ben-G, yes it's an unrecognized selector, but I'd rather diagnose the root cause.

Comment: I suppose the App does crash - when it runs as a release build?

Comment: Ok, everything with AH seems to go on the main_queue. If create a new thread for the block callback (when you click a button) the app crashes. I guess most people experience the crash in release build, but I just got with the debug

Comment: That's good.  Now I would guess that the callback is performing in the background and referencing a UIKit control, which is a huge no-no.  It may be that that, in conjunction with the unrecognized selector, is freezing your app.

Comment: ProTip:  If your app freezes in the debugger, then pause the debugger to see where the main thread is stuck.  It won't be exact, but it will get you going in the right direction.  Deadlocks are notoriously hard to diagnose (I just finished spending a few weeks on one).

Comment: @borrden, that's what I did with the image of the stack trace above :)

Comment: Oh, good job then.  Now that you mention it I see that you said that.    You should also check the other threads as well though (for example, I could see that the background core data thread was waiting for execution to complete and the main thread was waiting for that operation to complete)